# How to access windows d-drive through Linux?

Tags: linux, mount, windows, pop-os

I recently shifted from **windows to Linux (Pop OS)** and i wanted to a**ccess my Windows D-Drive in Linux** . I searched about this and found out that out that I need to mount my drive first of all , but as soon as I mounted my drives my system didn't boot and I had to reinstall Pop OS . I might be wrong in my research but i really want to get my files from D-drive .

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: How did you mount the drive? Mounting windows drive shouldn't affect the PopOS installation. You should be able to see the Windows drive in the Nautilus file manager and mount it just by clicking on "Other location" where you should see your extra drives.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I followed this "https://youtu.be/vAU5psrq8cc" tutorial to mount my drives and once I restarted the system after that , the booting got stuck on a PCIe Bus error . I tried to solve it but I could not , so I had to reinstall PopOS . Also after I reinstalled PopOS , I wasn't able to see any drives after clicking on other locations (which I could see earlier).

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I just found out that i got confused between drives and partition , I didn't know that installing some other OS wipes out all the partitions , I thought that I have 3 different hard disks (C drive , D drive and E drive) but they were just the partitions of the same hard disk and that means that my whole hard disk is wiped out . So is there any way to recover data from that hard disk ?

Comment: Anytime you make major changes you refresh your backup. So first suggestion is just reinstall Windows & restore your data. If you erased disk, not all data will be recoverable as some was overwritten. And if Windows some suggest Windows tools work better, but may cost. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu & http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_NTFS & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247461